# How to retrieve data from dynamically created user control in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have a user control which has text boxes and date picker. When the form loads, dynamically generate the user control and display in the form. 
(EventComponent (user control)).

[image: Screenshot]

I want to get each of these user control values when the user clicks the save button.

```
public partial class InsertEventForm : Form
{
    private int numberOfEvent;

    public InsertEventForm(int numberOfEvent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.numberOfEvent = numberOfEvent;
    }

    private void InsertEventForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EventComponent[] eventComponents = new EventComponent[(int)this.numberOfEvent];
        int i = 0;

        Button backBTN = new Button();
        backBTN.Text = "Back";
        backBTN.Location = new Point(0, 10);
        backBTN.Size = new Size(50, 30);
        this.Controls.Add(backBTN);

    // generate user control dynamically here

        for ( i = 0; i < eventComponents.Length; i++)
        {
            eventComponents[i] = new EventComponent();
            System.Drawing.Point pLabel = new System.Drawing.Point(36, 50 + i * 280);
            eventComponents[i].Location = pLabel;
            eventComponents[i].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(358, 259);
            this.Controls.Add(eventComponents[i]);
        }

        Button saveBTN = new Button();
        saveBTN.Text = "Save";
        saveBTN.Location = new Point(200, 50 + i * 280);
        saveBTN.Size = new Size(100, 50);
        this.Controls.Add(saveBTN);
        saveBTN.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.SaveBTN_click);
    }

    private void SaveBTN_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // need to retrieve value from user control
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is where you declared the controls.  You declared the controls inside methods so you cannot reference the controls inside other methods.  So declare backBTN in global space like : Button backBTN;  Then inside the  InsertEventForm_Load method assign the button : backBTN = new Button();

Comment: Make you eventComponents and saveBtn a field or property of the control and you can access it whereever your want.

Comment: I want to know where you set the value in the usercontrol.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1

create `List<EventComponent> EventComponentList`

when you add to `this.Controls`  add to the list

```
this.Controls.Add(eventComponents[i]);
EventComponentList.Add(eventComponents[i]);
```

Option 2 (Less recommended)

```
private void SaveBTN_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var list = this.Controls.OfType<EventComponent>().ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to MVVM, you'll have to create Model `Event` and every field would be a parameter of that class, later you create `ObservableCollection` that will be filled with objects of `Event` type every time you create the object clicking `save` button.